# How to find out, programmatically, which language is currently selected for Dictation? (Apple Watch)

Tags: xcode, swift, speech-recognition, apple-watch, dictation

I have an Apple watch app that works exclusively with English dictation. The reason no more languages are available is a long story so bear with me a while.
I know that doing a "hard press" on the screen, while dictation is going on with the nice voice graph, brings up a "choose language" menu where the user can select one of his available languages to do dictation with.

I want to find out programmatically, which language is currently being used for dictation, so that I can prompt the user to switch to English, if any other language is currently selected.

The menus, and everything on my phone is in English, but I also use German, Catalan and Spanish.

So far, I am using this code:

```
let language:NSString=NSLocale.preferredLanguages().first!
print("ASR(?) Language: "+(language as String))
```

But this, in fact, returns the System Language that is set in the main iOS Watch Map: General > Language and Region > System Language, not the Dictation Language.

...and this is the code I use for Dictation:

```
    self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions([], allowedInputMode: WKTextInputMode.Plain, completion:{(results) -> Void in
        let aResult = results?[0] as? String
        if(!(aResult == nil)){
            print(aResult)
            print("ASR says: "+aResult!)
        }//end if
    })//end show voice menu
```

Is it possible to detect which language is really the one being used for dictation?